Is Windows process a security principal distinct from its user?
The Microsoft doc page at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-security-principals says:

A security principal is any entity that can be authenticated by the operating system, such as a user account, a computer account, or a thread or process that runs in the security context of a user or computer account, or the security groups for these accounts.

Is a process indeed a security principal distinct from the user it runs as? If so, how does one get the process' SID?
The reason I'm wondering, it used to be that there were only two security authorities (i. e. principal containers) in Windows - the local SAM, and the domain. But these days there is more. IIS app pools, for example, or services - all security principals under their respective authorities. Who knows, maybe processes have one too.

No. Read your quotation again.

how does one get the process' SID - OpenProcess();OpenProcessToken();GetTokenInformation(TokenUser)

@RbAm: Won't that be the SID of the user that the process is running as?

Um, I'm seeing a sentence with the structure of "An S is any E..., such as a U, a C, or a T or a P."

No. Process can have any token . And user here unrelated. Usually child process inherit token from parent process. But we also can explicitly provide token for new process. Also process can inherit token from another process, not parent ( which call CreateProcessInternalW)

Also "process is running as user" how you understand this ? Only process token and relationship with user, logon and terminal session, etc. Anyway, what is your real question or problem?

Is it possible to secure a securable object against access by a specific unprivileged process (PID/handle known) while placing no restrictions on other processes running under the same user in the same session? Which boils down to - does a process have a SID (aside from the user SID) that can be placed inside an ACL?

Process have security descriptor. So of course you can set some custom security descriptor on it. Say allow access only from the same logon session. This of course will be work only for protect from not admin users, which have no debug privileges.
